# Disabling the Autocomplete in WFFM

Tags: wffm, security

Is there a possibility to disable the autocomplete of Sitecore WFFM text box.
We are using Sitecore 8.1

Comment: You mean Autofill? from browser cache?

Comment: This is regarding Autofill

Answer (score 1):

You may need to create custom SingleLineText field for this:

```
[ValidationProperty("Text")]
public class SingleLineText : Sitecore.Form.Web.UI.Controls.SingleLineText
{
    [VisualCategory("Custom Properties")]
    [VisualProperty("Autofill", 2)]
    [DefaultValue("off")]
    public string Autofill { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        // Set placeholder text, if present
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Autofill))
        {
            textbox.Attributes["autocomplete"] = Autofill;
        }

        base.OnInit(e);
    }
}
```

Then, You need to create field definition item under, Name it "Extended SingleLineText":

> /sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Field
>   Types/Custom/

Set the assembly name and class name to use the class you created for this field, Then you can use your new field which by default will disable autocomplete/autofill for you, since the autocomplete is set to "off".