# How to set autocomplete attribute for form fields

Tags: sitecore-forms

Using `Sitecore 10.2`

I would like to add `autocomplete=off` for these form fields - Single-Line, Multiline, Email.
Like any `Name Value List` field type where we can add custom attributes & values.

This [example](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/18641/creating-custom-data-attribute-for-sitecore-form-fields) suggests a custom solution which seems a lot for something that is very common & basic.

Is there any such OOB option or is a custom solution the only way.

Comment: Custom solution as explained in the ticket you linked is the only option.

Comment: For customization please refer to : https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/14203/disabling-the-autocomplete-in-wffm  but you can also update the view like <h4>@Html.Sitecore().Field(AllConstants.Title,  newsModel, new { @autocomplete = "off"})</h4>